# background disapear on mobile devices

Tags: css

I have this form here that disappear when I am on a mobile device. I really do not understand why? Can anybody help me figure that out? I have gone through the code, but I cannot find any solution on this.

```
.customclass h3{
    margin: 0 0 20px 0;
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #444;
    text-transform: none;
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 30px;
}

#form_over .formResponsive .formHorizontal .formControls {
    margin-left: 0
}
#form_over .formResponsive .formHorizontal .formControlLabel {
    float: none;
    width: auto;
    padding: 0px;
    text-align: left;
    margin-bottom: 5px
}
#form_over .formResponsive input[type="text"] {
    height: 35px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    font-size: 15px
}
#form_over .formResponsive .formHorizontal .rsform-block {
    margin-bottom: 0
}
#form_over .formResponsive .formBody #tilmeld {
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: 18px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: #166687;
    background-image: none;
    line-height: 50px;
    padding-left: 25px;
    padding-right: 25px;
    width: 98% !important;
    max-width: 98% !important;
    border: none;
    text-shadow: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none
}
#form_over .formResponsive .formBody #modtag {
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: 18px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: #166687;
    background-image: none;
    line-height: 50px;
    padding-left: 25px;
    padding-right: 25px;
    width: 98% !important;
    max-width: 98% !important;
    border: none;
    text-shadow: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
  background-color: #F1A900;
}
#form_over .formResponsive input {
    width: 92%
}
#form_over .formResponsive {
    margin-bottom: 0
}
```

Comment: what is disappearing? I cannot reproduce the problem by Google Chrome debug tools

Comment: I checked your link here and your form looks fine on all devices.

Comment: really+ But there is no grey background like on the desktop view?`

Comment: Are you sure it disappears and not just moves down?

Comment: The background is white, but the inputs and the button are fine.

Comment: Ok. Why is it getting white? I would like to keep the grey colour

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `custom.css` file you have following code:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) { /* mobile devices */

  .customclass {
    position: relative;
    top: 0px; 
    right: 0%;
    z-index: 100;
    height: 74%;
    background: white;
    padding: 0 50px;
    }
}
```

As you can see the styles for the form are overridden when the screen is 767px wide or less. Just remove `background: white;` and you'll be fine.

Comment: Exactly! You answered first haha :).

Or put "background: #EFEFEF"